# Using Tags for a child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, image-resolution

I have tried to make a model swapping system for a game without having to make scripts for each model that changes , essentially each model changes from a low-quality model to a high-quality one and vise Versa , I was thinking the best way would be to have one model as a child and have it tagged as high quality and then have the script find the model for that object by finding its child with that tag.

If anybody has any suggestions as to how I could do this or just point me somewhere to look that be great , I have been looking around but haven't found anything.

Comment: I don't know much about gamedev and the question is pretty broad, but you could probably use generics (write one model swapping script and use it for all models). Or you can use attributes as that Tags you are speaking about and get the model you need via reflection, but it seems like a bad solution especially when speed matters.

Comment: as you suggested i am trying to make just one script that finds a child with a tag , so for every model this script is attached to it finds the child with the tag , thats what im trying to accomplish , thanks for your input.

Comment: This is way to broad. We don't even know how your game engine looks like. Are you using Unity by chance?

Comment: Yes i am , newest version , C#